# Delphi: How to calculate the SHA hash of a large file

Tags: delphi, sha

Hi I need to generate a SHA over a 5 Gig file

Do you know of a non string based Delphi library that can do this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [DCPcrypt v2](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/cryptography.html) and read your file buffered and feed the SHA hasher with the buffer until you've read the complete 5GB file.

If you want to know how to read a large file buffered, see my answer [about a file copy using custom buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438260/delphi-fast-file-copy/438323#438323).

so in concept (no real delphi code!):

```
function GetShaHash(const AFilename: String)
begin
  sha := TSHAHasher.Create;
  SetLength(Result, sha.Size);
  file := OpenFile(AFilename, GENERIC_READ);
  while not eof file do
  begin
     BytesRead := ReadFile(file, buffer[0], 0, 1024 * 1024);
     sha.Update(buffer[0], BytesRead);
  end;
  sha.Final(Result[0]); 
  CloseFile(file);
end;
```

Comment: I didn't include real Delphi code because I don't have a Delphi compiler installed at the moment.

Comment: I can also recommend HashLib4Pascal!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend Wolfgang Ehrhardt's CRC/Hash. 
http://home.netsurf.de/wolfgang.ehrhardt/

It's fast and "can be compiled with most current Pascal (TP 5/5.5/6, BP 7, VP 2.1, FPC 1.0/2.0/2.2) and Delphi versions (tested with V1 up to V7/9/10)".

I've used it with D11/D12 too.

Comment: yeah, that's a nice one too, very nice asm optimalizations :)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Indy comes with several a stream based hash methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Delphi interface for OpenSSL, isn't there?

That should provide you with better performances.

Answer (score 0):

@Davy Landman,
thank you, your answer really helped me out. This is the code I ended up using:

```
function HashFileSHA256(const fileName: String): String;
var
  sha256: TDCP_sha256;
  buffer: array[0..1024*1024] of byte;
  i, bytesRead: Integer;
  streamIn: TFileStream;
  hashBuf: array[0..31] of byte;
begin
  // Initialization
  Result := '';
  streamIn := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead);
  sha256 := TDCP_sha256.Create(nil);
  for i:=0 to Sizeof(buffer) do
    buffer[i] := 0;
  for i:=0 to Sizeof(hashBuf) do
    hashBuf[i] := 0;
  bytesRead := -1;

  // Compute
  try
    sha256.Init;
    while bytesRead <> 0 do
    begin
      bytesRead := streamIn.Read(buffer[0], Sizeof(buffer));
      sha256.Update(buffer[0], bytesRead);
    end;
    sha256.Final(hashBuf);
    for I := 0 to 31 do
      Result := Result + IntToHex(hashBuf[i], 2);
  finally
    streamIn.Free;
    sha256.Free;
  end;

  Result := LowerCase(Result);
end;
```

P.S.: I am a total beginner with Pascal, so this code most likely sucks. But I tested it on the MSYS2 installer and was able to verify the hash, so that's nice.