# How do you display an XMPP (Jabber) vcard photo in Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi, xmpp, vcf-vcard

How can I read a photo from an XMPP vcard (an avatar picture, which I think is in JPEG format) and display it in a Delphi TImage control?

The XMPP server sends this XML:

```
<presence id="e3T50-75" to="cvg@esx10-2022/spark" from="semra@esx10-2022" 
 type="unavailable">
  <x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update">
    <photo>897ce4538a4568f2e3c4838c69a0d60870c4fa49</photo>
  </x>
  <x xmlns="jabber:x:avatar">
    <hash>897ce4538a4568f2e3c4838c69a0d60870c4fa49</hash>
  </x>
</presence>
```

Comment: this is a phyton example but i need delphi
http://collincode.wordpress.com/2009/01/31/xmpp-jabber-photo-module-2/

Comment: As the Python function `recieve_vcard()` shows this is just base64-encoded data. Use the "[delphi] base64" search on StackOverflow to find lots of links and example code for encoding and decoding this format.

Comment: @mghie: Why not write this as an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: @Lars: I don't consider this an answer, merely a helpful nudge into the right direction. Hopefully someone (maybe even the OP) posts some code that answers the question. I only had a quick look at the linked Python code.

Comment: Thanks Rob Kenndy but i have get some error Jpeg error #53

implementation
  uses omnixmlutils;
{$R *.dfm}

...function ChooseGraphicClass(const MimeType: string): TGraphicClass;

...function CreateGraphicFromVCardPhoto(const BinVal, MimeType: string): TGraphic;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   memo1.lines.loadfromfile('c:\cvg.bin');
   image1.Picture.Graphic :=  CreateGraphicFromVCardPhoto(memo1.text,'image/jpeg');
end;

{ cvg.bin file is here 
http://www.anasel.com.tr/cvgxml.txt
}
{ http://www.anasel.com.tr/cvg.bin}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XML you posted does not contain the picture. It contains the [SHA-1 hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553310/delphi-how-to-calculate-the-sha-hash-of-a-large-file) of the picture's contents. You only get the hash, initially, in case you have already fetched that image once before, so you can display the cached version instead of requesting it anew.

If you don't have an image with that hash, then request a new vcard. When it arrives, read the `PHOTO` element, if it's available. It may have two subelements, `BINVAL` and `TYPE`. `BINVAL` will contain the Base-64-encoded version of the image, and `TYPE` will contain the MIME type identifier for the image type, such as *image/jpeg* or *image/png*.

Decode the binary data and store it in a stream, such as `TFileStream` or `TMemoryStream`. Next, choose which `TGraphic` descendant is appropriate for the kind of image you have. It might be `TPngImage`, or it might be `TBitmap`. Instantiate the class, and tell it to load the stream's contents. It would go something like this:

```
function CreateGraphicFromVCardPhoto(const BinVal, MimeType: string): TGraphic;
var
  Stream: TStream;
  GraphicClass: TGraphicClass;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if not Base64Decode(BinVal, Stream) then
      raise EBase64Decode.Create;
    Stream.Position := 0;
    GraphicClass := ChooseGraphicClass(MimeType);
    Result := GraphicClass.Create;
    try
      Result.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The code above uses the `Base64Decode` function from [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/), described in the answer to [*Saving a Base64 string to disk as a binary using Delphi 2007*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690475/saving-a-base64-string-to-disk-as-a-binary-using-delphi-2007). Once you have the `TGraphic` value, you can assign it to a `TImage` or do whatever else you can do with `TGraphic`s.

The `ChooseGraphicClass` function might work like this:

```
function ChooseGraphicClass(const MimeType: string): TGraphicClass;
begin
  if MimeType = 'image/bmp' then
    Result := TBitmap
  else if MimeType = 'image/png' then
    Result := TPngImage
  else if MimeType = 'image/gif' then
    Result := TGifImage
  else if MimeType = 'image/jpeg' then
    Result := TJpegImage
  else
    raise EUnknownGraphicFormat.Create(MimeType);
end;
```

Comment: Awesome answer, Rob!
Suggestion: add an example vCard XML.

Comment: No can do. I've never seen such a thing. I assume that the people who need this code already know how to get a vcard. If they don't, they're free to ask a new question here.

Comment: Thanks Rob Kenndy but i have get some error Jpeg error #53 implementation uses omnixmlutils; {$R *.dfm} ...function ChooseGraphicClass(const MimeType: string): TGraphicClass; ...function CreateGraphicFromVCardPhoto(const BinVal, MimeType: string): TGraphic; procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); begin memo1.lines.loadfromfile('c:\cvg.bin'); image1.Picture.Graphic := CreateGraphicFromVCardPhoto(memo1.text,'image/jpeg'); end; { cvg.bin file is here http://www.anasel.com.tr/cvgxml.txt } { http://www.anasel.com.tr/cvg.bin}

Comment: Delphi's JPEG library can't handle all JPEG files. http://newsgroups.archived.at/borland/public.delphi.graphics/200608/0608162573.html

Comment: Yes Robert, delphi cant handle all type jpeg. i use this procedure and memo1.lines.savetofile... savetodisk and see then right picture.

procedure SaveBase64ToFile(const encoded, fileName: string);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  try
    if not Base64Decode(encoded, fs) then
      raise Exception.Create('Invalid data!');
  finally FreeAndNil(fs); end;
end;