# Delphi - Folder Synchronization over network

Tags: delphi, networking, synchronization, file-copying

I have an  application that connects to a database and can be used in multi-user mode, whereby multiple computers can connect the the same database server to view and modify data. One of the clients is always designated to be the 'Master' client. This master also receives text information from either RS232 or UDP input and logs this data every second to a text file on the local machine.

My issue is that the other clients need to access this data from the Master client. I am just wondering the best and most efficient way to proceed to solve this problem. I am considering two options:

1. Write a folder synchronize class to synchronize the folder on the remote (Master) computer with the folder on the local (client) computer. This would be a threaded, buffered file copying routine.
2. Implement a client/server so that the Master computer can serve this data to any client that connects and requests the data. The master would send the file over TCP/UDP to the requesting client.

The solution will have to take the following into account:

a. The log files are being written to every second. It must avoid any potential file locking issues.

b. The copying routine should only copy files that have been modified at a later date than the ones already on the client machine.

c. Be as efficient as possible

d. All machines are on a LAN

e. The synchronization need only be performed, say, every 10 minutes or so.

f. The amount of data is only in the order of ~50MB, but once the initial (first) sync is complete, then the amount of data to transfer would only be in the order of ~1MB. This will increase in the future

Which would be the better method to use? What are the pros/cons? I have also seen the [Fast File Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438260/delphi-fast-file-copy) post which i am considering using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a database, why the "master" writes data to a text file instead of to the database, if those data needs to be shared?

Comment: The amount of 'useful' data in these text files is insignificant compared to the storage requirements if i was to store it in the database. I had considered this but decided not to store it all, for numerous reasons

Comment: So to save cheap disk space on the database server you spend time to implement a complex file based sync solution replicating the very same data n times instead of storing them once into a database, which would solve the concurrent access nicely also?

Comment: Yea i know, however there are other reasons why this happens. I will only ever need approx 0.001% of this data and backup times on the DB server are critical. The 'cheap disk space' is not actually cheap in this particular instance, as DB data needs to be kept to a minimum due to a lack of cheap internet access onsite - the data needs to be sent via expensive satellite comms in an extremely remote location. It is a good point though thanks.

Comment: Don't know what database you're using, but if database backups are critical you can use two separate DBs (or schemas), one for the data and one for the logs, so you can backup them separately. What data needs to be sent through sat comms? Is the DB remote? If so use another DB in the local LAN (paragraph d above) and use it for the logs.

Comment: +1 because truthfully the database solution is really the easiest to implement, and it's also "portable" (works over TCP/IP, you can access it from wherever). Any open-source (ie: no licensing costs) db would do, the storage overhead would be minimal.

Comment: @ldsandon that is a good idea, i think i will seriously consider using a separate DB. Currently using MySQL. The Main DB is only around 100K when compressed and this needs to be sent through sat comms. The secondary DB would grow considerably over time, approx 10Mb per day, over multiple years. Hopefully searching (via a DateTime field will still be as quick as my current routine, which only takes about 20-50ms for each query)

Comment: How long do you need to keep data online? You can also keep a "rolling windows" and delete at proper intervals data no longer needed (partitioning is really useful for such tasks). If database table, indexes, caches and queries are well tuned it will be very fast. Depending on your data layout and usage, you can also think about a NoSQL database.

Comment: Data can be archived every year. I can see in the order of 15-20 million rows per year.

Comment: If you have to store about 10MB per day it's about 4GB per year which is a very small amount today. Even if you select a SAS RAID 1 or 10 15k RAID system you would get 146 GB disks at a reasonable price - it's 30 years of storage... if you use MySQL 5.5 I'd suggest to try partitioning for manageability and speed reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Why invent the wheel? Use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead. Package for windows: [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650).

For example, on the Master machine install rsync server, and on the client machines install rsync clients or simply drop files in your project directory. Whenever needed your application on a client machine shall [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901860/delphi-7-how-to-execute-shell-command-and-check-the-result) rsync.exe requesting to synchronize necessary files from the server.

In order to copy open files you will need to setup Windows Volume Shadow Copy service. [Here's](http://www.goodjobsucking.com/?p=62) a very detailed description on how the Master machine can be setup to allow copying of open files using Windows Volume Shadow Copy.

Comment: +1 for rsync. Last time I needed this, I spent a long time working on a solution in delphi. Then I gave up and installed RSYNC and used it instead, and never looked back.  It's a unix/linux utility but it works great in windows, and there's a windows installer/service already built.

Comment: I'm using rsync allot, both on Windows and Linux; It's a Linux tool that hasn't found a good home on Windows yet. The Windows port (using cygwin) has bugs, it sometimes doesn't work for unknown reasons. 99% of the time it works as expected, and I use it because 99% is good enough for me, but if 100% reliability is required, it's not the way to go!

Comment: @Simon, `rsync`, with it's Linux roots, can be easily controlled from the command line and returns meaningful status codes that can be used to verify if execution was successful.

Comment: rsync is great, but I don't have good experiences with rsync on windows (and specially over shares). File length limits, file name limitations, interrupted actions etc.

Answer (score 2):

Write a web service interface, so that the clients an connect to the server and pull new data as needed.  Or, you could write it as a subscribe/push mechanism so that clients connect to the server, "subscribe", and then the server pushes all new content to the registered clients.  Clients would need to fully sync (get all changes since last sync) when registering, in case they were offline when updates occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions would work just fine on the LAN, the choice is yours. You might want to also consider those issues related to the technology you choose:

- Deployment flexibility. Using file shares and file copy requires file sharing to work, and all LAN users might gain access to the log files.
- Longer term plans: File shares are only good on the local network, while IP based solutions work over routed networks, including Internet.
- The file-based solution would be significantly easier to implement compared to the IP solution.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the additional issues. As this software will only ever be used over LAN (as it is always in a remote location without internet), i dont have to worry about that. I was thinking file based would be easier too